# In VB.NET Console application, how to get application's setting from My.Settings object?

Tags: vb.net, properties, application-settings

I have Paste/Copy following code from a `VB.NET` Winform application to a `VB.NET` **Console** application

```
    Dim oSettings = New My.Settings
    sTracePath = oSettings.TracePath
    sDataFolder = oSettings.DataFolder
```

I have also tried to define/create a Setting file in `MyProject` folder as done for WinForm application; but builder continue to return following compiler error on first line of code !

```
My.Settings type is not defined
```

I have also tried to Paste/Copy `Settings.settings` and `Settings.Designer.vb` files from WinForm application to  my Console application; but it doesn't work.

How can define a `My.Settings` object in a VB.NET **Console** application so that I can access directly a Property as `TracePath` or `DataFolder` without using a String Key but in using a variable name ?

Is that possible for `Console` VB.NET applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `The Truth Is Out There` !

The correct VB.NET code is

```
Dim oSettings = New My.MySettings
```

or

```
Dim oSettings = My.Settings
```

but not

```
Dim oSettings = New My.Settings
```

`My.MySettings` is the type and `My.Settings` is a predefined objet of `My.MySettings` type !

You can immediately use `My.Settings` instead of `oSettings` !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not for .NET core apps (which is what I get the feeling you're using)

Core:

[image]

Std:

[image]

If your project properties looks like the top, you've made a core project and settings as you know it is unavailable (there is a settings system in core but it differs to the one you seek). If it looks like the bottom hen you should be able to select settings on the left and create a file by clicking if it doesn't exist. The My namespace has to be referenced/imported too. Without it, you can access settings like Properties.Setting.Default.Setting1 etc

Comment: I will test your proposal. My project is not .Net Core project but, at begin it was a .Net Core 3.1. I have migrated in adapting <TargetFramework> as found on a web page that I don't find again.